# While statement on Octave

Tags: while-loop, octave

I have a problem with this while on Octave:

```
while(k<=1.0)
    imshow(cv*k+id*(1-k));
    disp(k);
    k=k+0.04;
    pause(0.1);
endwhile
```

And this is the output of the values of `k`:

```
0
0.040000
0.080000
0.12000
0.16000
0.20000
0.24000
0.28000
0.32000
0.36000
0.40000
0.44000
0.48000
0.52000
0.56000
0.60000
0.64000
0.68000
0.72000
0.76000
0.80000
0.84000
0.88000
0.92000
0.96000
```

Why does `k` never reach `1` even if I entered `<=` in the `while` condition?

Comment: seems to be the floating point issue. Check out these posts: [Why is 24.0000 not equal to 24.0000 in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/686439/5698672) and [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/5698672). Also see how to create a [mre]

Comment: Repeatedly adding a value to a variable enhances the rounding errors in foisting:point arithmetic. Never use a float as a loop condition, use integers instead. Or create your values for k first: `for k = linspace(0, 1, 26);`.

Comment: Change `disp(k);` to `fprintf('%.17f\n', k);`